# Remove upload file types filter for admin

Tags: uploads, capabilities

Does anyone know if there is a function to remove/bypass file types uploads filter (specifically for admins). I know there are plugins available but they often break or don't contain ALL the mime types I need to allow and to be completely honest I'm just tired of dealing with this constantly. I also know about the constant ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS which I'm using currently, but eventually I need only for the admin to be able to upload without restriction. I'm not sure how to do this in config file. Tried searching for a resolution but only found for allowing specific file types.

Answer (score 0):

This is example for only doc file for admin.

You are also add another file to avoid restriction for admin.

```
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'file_and_ext_allow_for_user', 10, 4 );
function file_and_ext_allow_for_user( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes )
{
    if( is_admin() ){
        if( false !== strpos( $filename, '.doc' ) )
        {
            $types['ext'] = 'doc';
            $types['type'] = 'application/msword';
        }
    }

    return $types;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Hoping to avoid having to maintain a list of file types though and completely remove WordPress' MIME check altogether. I found this https://secure.wphackedhelp.com/blog/fix-file-type-not-permitted-for-security-reasons-wordpress-error/ searching last night but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my mistake. I didn't realize setting ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS=true ONLY applies to admins already. Which might explain why it was difficult to find an answer to my original question. Woops! Source: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/new-wp-config-tweaks-you-probably-dont-know--wp-35396